# FLOT Tooltip placement?

Tags: jquery, html, date, time, flot

There doesn't appear to be a way to move the tooltip in my graph from showing up on the bottom right? This seems very intuitive but I can't find a way to put it above or to the left of the datapoint. Any suggestions? Thanks

I was thinking that changing the top/bottom, left/right in the funciton would do it but no luck

`code`

```
function showTooltip(x, y, contents) {
            $('<div id="tooltip">' + contents + '</div>').css( {
                position: 'absolute',
                display: 'none',
                bottom:  y - 35,
                left:  x + 10,
                border: '1px solid #fdd',
                padding: '2px',
                'background-color': '#fee',
                opacity: 0.80
            }).appendTo("body").fadeIn(200);
         }
```

`code`

[image]

Comment: I have the tooltip example below working but not the problem of tooltip placement above the data point and to the left... any ideas?

 http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/interacting.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your syntax, it looks like the [combination of top and left](http://jsfiddle.net/ugyCw/1/) place it pretty well (disclaimer, I only have Firefox handy to try it).

```
   function showTooltip(x, y, contents) {
       $('<div id="tooltip">' + contents + '</div>').css( {
            position: 'absolute',
            display: 'none',
            top:  y - 40,
            left:  x - 100,
            border: '1px solid #fdd',
            padding: '2px',
            'background-color': '#fee',
            opacity: 0.80
        }).appendTo("body").fadeIn(200);

   }
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help Mark - perhaps it is the browser because it does not work like that in IE 8.

Comment: I apologize Mark - this does work in IE. For some reason when I changed it on all four graphs it worked. Not sure whats going on but Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Craig qTip 2 plug-in to get a better looking tooltip and (I am almost sure) the ability to move the tool tip where you want from the point.
Here you can find an example: `http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/demos/flot` and the lowwing link bring you to the whole page of the awesome plug-in `http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/demos/`

That's the code used in the posted example, maybe it could be useful for your purpose...

```
// Create a tooltip on our chart
elem.qtip({
    prerender: true,
    content: 'Loading...', // Use a loading message primarily
    position: {
        viewport: $(window), // Keep it visible within the window if possible
        target: 'mouse', // Position it in relation to the mouse
        adjust: { x: 7 } // ...but adjust it a bit so it doesn't overlap it.
    },
    show: false, // We'll show it programatically, so no show event is needed
    style: {
        classes: 'ui-tooltip-shadow ui-tooltip-tipsy',
        tip: false // Remove the default tip.
    }
});
```

I am studying lots of Flot practical application so we should keep ourself in touch as this plug-in doesn't have a great guide.